# Change link URL based on select input

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, alpine.js

Using the latest `alpine.js` build, I am interested in having a select input that I am building in Laravel that looks something as trivial as this:

```
{{ Form::select('dogs', $dogs) }}
```

The above is using `LaravelCollective HTML` packaging for easy form building.

Now, when one of the options above is selected, I want the value currently selected to update the anchor tag below:

```
<a href="{{ route('dog', ['dog'=>$selectedDog]) }}">Pet Dog</a>
```

I have a stub `href` attribute, but I want it to dynamically update and I believe using some kind of `alpine.js` binding would work here.

Does it make sense to use `x-on` for when the select option gets updated and then perhaps use `x-bind` against the `href`? What's the right way to approach this so the URL gets updated according to the currently selected option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've suggested is correct: you want to bind the `href` attribute so that it initialises to the current route but you'll also want to be able to update it. In order to do that you'll want a `url` property on `x-data` (Alpine.js state).

This all looks something like the following:

```
<a 
  x-data="{ url: '{{ route('dog', ['dog'=>$selectedDog]) }}' }"
  href="{{ route('dog', ['dog'=>$selectedDog]) }}"
  x-bind:href="url"
>
  Pet Dog
</a>
```

On the `select` side, you'll want to use `x-on:change` to pick up any changes, then you'll want to broadcast them using a custom event. In Alpine.js this can be done using `$dispatch`.

In raw HTML you would do:

```html
<select x-on:change="$dispatch('selection-change', { value: $event.target.value })">
  <option value="first-option">First option</option>
</select>
```

Which can be mapped to LaravelCollective HTML:

```
{{ Form::select('dogs', $dogs, ['x-on:change' => '$dispatch("selection-change", { value: $event.target.value })'] }}
```

Finally you'll need to handle the `selection-change` custom event in your `a`, using `x-on:selection-change.window` or `x-on:selection-change.document` (`.window/.document` attach the listener to the window or document instead of the element on which the directive/attribute is placed). You'll probably want to compute the new `url` and `text` based on the `value`.

```
<a 
  x-data="{ url: '{{ route('dog', ['dog'=>$selectedDog]) }}', selectedDog: '{{ $selectedDog }}' }"
  href="{{ route('dog', ['dog'=>$selectedDog]) }}"
  x-on:selection-change.window="
    url = url.replace(selectedDog, $event.detail.value);
    selectedDog = $event.detail.value;
  "
  x-bind:href="url"
>
  Pet Dog
</a>
```

Comment: shouldn't `x-on:selection-change.window` manipulated `$selectedDog` somehow?

Comment: Yeah you'll probably want to stick `$selectedDog` into the Alpine.js state (x-data) and then replace that in the string with `event.detail.value`

Comment: It looks like you are declaring the `url` data property, but aren't using it in `href`. Is that intentional? Not sure I'm seeing a use for it at this point.

Comment: It is being used in `x-bind:href="url`

Comment: I've updated the answer to include how you could update the URL per my earlier suggestion in a comment

Comment: Escaping is extremely problematic with Alpine + Laravel. It does not like `$selectedDog` interpolation in the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

It will 100% work when you are using alpine js. On select value update the href link.

```
@php
    $theaters = collect(setting('theaters'))->sort();

    $theaters = ['hello@gmail.com', 'hello@gmail1.com', 'hello2@gamil.com'];

@endphp

<div x-data="{ foo: 'Not selected' }">
    <select @change="foo = $event.target.value"
        class="font-thin py-4 px-4 block w-full shadow-sm border-gray border-2 rounded-md focus:border-primary-400 focus:ring-primary-400">
        @foreach ($theaters as $key => $theater)
            <option x-bind:value="'mailto:{{ $theater['email'] }}'">{{ $theater['email'] }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <br>
    <a class="rounded font-roboto bg-primary text-lg py-6 px-16 uppercase text-white inline-block hover:opacity-75"
        :href="foo" title="Email about Open Positions">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```